# Google play Admob privacy policy

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have been sent the following email from Google Play store. My app has ads provided by Admob which i am sure is what is causing this issue. For iOS i added the privacy information in the info.plist which was ok for Apple however Google wants me to add a privacy policy and link it in the store listing.

Has anyone had this issue before? My app is just a game that doesn't access any information from the user it could only be the ads causing it.

> "Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid
>   privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or
>   device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g.
>   camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but
>   does not include a valid privacy policy.
>
> Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your
>   app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more
>   information in our help centre."

Comment: No it can never be because of ads, this might be because possibly you are using an plugin which requires these additional permissions

Comment: When i uploaded to iOS App Store, i had to add fields that said Admob can access Bluetooth peripheral, Photo Library and Calendars. However, i haven't done this for Android as there is no info.plist file. There are no other plugins used.

Comment: Please list of all permissions used in your app

Comment: @AmodGokhale Privacy - Photo Library Usage, Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage, Privacy - Calendars Usage.

Comment: there you go ( Calendars )  you need to make sure appropriate privacy policy is linked on google play store console https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/user-data// ( You need to link it in play store admin console - > Store listing > last settings. For a privacy policy language refer to your legal department

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I'm qualified to give you a more detailed answer. I also have apps on the App Store (iOS) and recently researched the whole Google Play privacy policy issue at length - the reason being that I've worked on a (mobile) privacy policy generator for years.

Your issue doesn't seem to be one and Google's email is vague - it says it *could* be a permissions issue, OR a user data issue.

Ads are among the more intrusive things one can do and certainly warrant a privacy policy by itself, accessing "dangerous" permissions is another one.

Additionally, the fact that Apple let your app through and Google didn't, isn't a hint at everything being ok on the side of the App Store, btw.

What you must do to fix:

**1) Add statements about using Admob into your privacy policy**

Your use of Admob is subject to the [Admob programme policies](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/), which says:

> Privacy
>   You must disclose clearly any data collection, sharing and
>   usage that takes place on any site, app or other property as a
>   consequence of your use of any Google advertising service. To comply
>   with this disclosure obligation with respect to Google’s use of data,
>   you have the option to display a prominent link to How Google uses
>   data when you use our partners’ sites or apps.

**2) Add statements about your use of any dangerous permissions like the following**

CALENDAR
READ_CALENDAR
WRITE_CALENDAR
CAMERA
CAMERA
CONTACTS
READ_CONTACTS
WRITE_CONTACTS
GET_ACCOUNTS
LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
MICROPHONE
RECORD_AUDIO
PHONE
READ_PHONE_STATE
CALL_PHONE
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
ADD_VOICEMAIL
USE_SIP
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
SENSORS 
BODY_SENSORS
SMS 
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
RECEIVE_MMS
STORAGE 
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**3) What else belongs in your privacy policy (very superficial overview)**

Here's some more information that might help you in getting this done well:

- Outline which dangerous/sensitive permissions you request
- Outline any other user data you collect, for instance advertisement services!
- Describe what purpose they serve and use them only for that purpose
- Information about the site/app owner.
- The kind of data being collected and how it is collected.
- The purpose of the data collection (i.e. analytics, email marketing).
- Any third parties that have access to the information and through which means (widgets and integrations).
- The rights of users regarding their data (i.e. the ability to request to see the data, to rectify, erase, or block).
- The process for notifying users and visitors regarding material changes to the privacy policy.
- Effective date of the privacy policy.

To conclude. This isn't an easy job for anyone that isn't a privacy professional. Even for lawyers this takes a lot of reading usually. For this reason I'll link to two posts that go into the nitty gritty details:

- [How to create a privacy policy for Android apps](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/)
- [How to solve a Google Play Developer Policy violation](http://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/)

I hope this helps :)